# add if/else logic to JavaScript filter

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which I filter with two different arrays.
The array is a list of study classes that I want to filter by grade and subject.

I came up with this code:

```
this.schoolActivity.filter(x => {
    return (
        this.activeSubjects.includes(x.subject.toLowerCase()) &&
        this.activeGrades.includes(x.grade)
    );
});
```

which works fine but the issue here is that if there are no active subjects (subject to filter by) or the same for a grade, then nothing returns.
Any idea how can I improve this filter by adding logic to the only filter by subject/grade if active ones exist?

Comment: What does "no active subjects" mean? `x.subject` is blank, or `this.activeSubjects` is empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add an `||` check to see if the length of the array in question is 0:

```
const { activeSubjects, activeGrades } = this;
this.schoolActivity.filter(x => {
  return (
    (activeSubjects.length === 0 || activeSubjects.includes(x.subject.toLowerCase())) &&
    (activeGrades.length === 0 || activeGrades.includes(x.grade))
  );
});
```

You could improve the computational complexity to `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)` by using a couple of Sets instead of `includes`, but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you probably interpreted "no active subjects" better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to skip the filter on `x.subject` if it's blank. In which case:

```
this.schoolActivity.filter(x => {
    return (
      (!x.subject || this.activeSubjects.includes(x.subject.toLowerCase())) &&
      this.activeGrades.includes(x.grade)
    );
  });
```

The first condition will be true if `x.subject` is blank *or* it isn't blank and is on the list of active subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to check if active Subjects & active grades exist

```
    this.schoolActivity.filter(x => {
        return (
            if(typeof this.activeSubjects !== 'undefined' && this.activeSubjects.length && typeof this.activeGrades !== 'undefined' && this.activeSubjects.length){
                this.activeSubjects.includes(x.subject.toLowerCase()) && this.activeGrades.includes(x.grade)
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

If I get your point then

```
this.schoolActivity.filter(x => {
    return (
      (this.activeSubjects && this.activeSubjects.includes(x.subject.toLowerCase())) &&
      (this.activeGrades && this.activeGrades.includes(x.grade))
    );
  });
```